# ios load content from website

Tags: ios, web, load

I want to create native iOS app, which must display static content of some website (for example, news website). I just need to display news categories, articles' text and images in my native iOS app.

How is it better to get content of website? What is the usual way to do that?
Ask website's developers for website's api? Or using some iOS SDK tools to get web content?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Asking the webmaster for the API is the best and easiest way, if they provide.
2. You can get the specific content you need via crawling script
   written by Python. Run the python script on your own server to fetch
   the articles under news category over and over, analyze the content 
   and extract the useful part, finally provide your own API for your native iOS app. This costs more.
3. Straightway, create NSURLRequest to load the webpage content, and do
   the analysis task on the client instead. This affects the user experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `UIWebView` to load websites.

If the developer provides you a website API with XML or JSON you can create a `UITableView` with the news titles and a `UIViewController` to load the news details, but I don't think any developer would do it for you.